# C++ structure with cin.get

Tags: c++, structure

I'm new here!

I'm beginner in programing. Now I doing some exercises from my book and I have question - why in

```
cin.get(ps->volume);
```

show me error? Here's my whole code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct inflatable //definicja struktury
{
   char name[20];
   float volume;
   double price;
};

int main()
{
   inflatable *ps = new inflatable; //alokacja pamieci na strukture, dynamiczne
   cout << "Podaj nazwe dmuchanej zabawki: ";
   cin.get(ps->name,20); //metoda pierwsza dostepu do pól
   cout << "Podaj objetosc w centymetrach: ";
   //cin >> (*ps).volume; //metoda druga dostepu do pól
   cin.get(ps->volume);
   cout << "Podaj cene (zl): ";
   cin >> ps->price;
   cout << "Nazwa: " << (*ps).name << endl;
   cout << "Objetosc: " << ps->volume << " centymetrow." << endl; //metoda 1
   cout << "Cena: " << ps->price << " zl." << endl; //metoda 1
   delete ps;

   return 0;
}
```

I know this line is good

```
//cin >> (*ps).volume; //metoda druga dostepu do pól
```

But I want to understand why I can't use line at the beginning of my post.

Comment: Did you check the parameter types of [`cin.get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)? What did it tell you?

Comment: You want to use formatted input, as you are using formatted output... `std::cin >> ps->volume;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, cin.get() is used for characters.
The volume declared there is a float so it should be:

```
cin>>ps->volume;
```

Comment: Ahhh, so cin.get() is used only for characters? I did a few examples and I had to forget that.

Comment: Yes, you can see what parameters should be passed to it here.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

Comment: @falauthy Please upvote and choose as accepted answer if I helped.